# Does TCAS II equipment satisfy the required ADS-B installation?

Tags: faa-regulations, avionics, easa-regulations, ads-b, tcas

The title says it all.

If TCAS II is installed and functioning, does it satisfy the ADS-B OUT mandates?

Comment: They're not entirely separate. Some implementations of ADS-B use a 1090 MHz Mode S transponder, which is also a required component of a compliant TCAS II installation.  The position source required for ADS-B is separate, however. I think it's a reasonable question.

Comment: No to ADS-B OUT. Mode S transponders broadcast on 1090 MHz and can be designed to support ADS-B OUT. TCAS II receives on 1090 MHz so in addition to the TCAS function TCAS is capable of supporting ADS-B IN. Most of these ADS-B IN capable TCAS just receive the ADS-B messages, package them into reports and forward them to a separate processor that contains the ADS-B IN applications.

Answer (score 1):

TCAS II and ADS-B are two entirely different systems, with entirely different functions, and they have different regulations. Having TCAS II installed & functioning does not satisfy any of the ADS-B OUT mandates.

### ADS-B regulations European Union

For Europe, the regulations for ADS-B are published in the surveillance performance and interoperability requirements Implementing Rule (SPI-IR), Commission Implementing Regulation (EU) [No 1207/2011](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1512642217096&uri=CELEX:32011R1207), amended by Commission Implementing Regulation (EU)  [No 1028/2014](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=uriserv%3AOJ.L_.2014.284.01.0007.01.ENG) and Commission Implementing Regulation (EU) [2017/386](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1512642217096&uri=CELEX:32017R0386).

### TCAS regulations European Union

TCAS II, version 7.1 is regulated by Commission Regulation (EU) [No 1332/2011](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32011R1332) amended  Commission Regulation (EU) [2016/918](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32016R0918).